# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called because of UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using `UITapGestureRecognizer` to end editing (because that's the workaround I found useful to end editing on input keyboards that have no other way to do so, like the Decimal Pad). The problem is that inside that `viewController` I have a `tableView` (the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` of that `tableView` are set to the `viewController`) and the method **`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`** is not being triggered.

Code:

```
viewDidLoad {
   ...
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
   ...
}


- (void)tap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gr {
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   NSLog(@"Help!");
}
```

I know the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is catching the selection, because if I comment out as following:

```
viewDidLoad {
   ...
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
   //[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
   ...
}
```

now the method the **`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`** finally triggers out.

I need help with some good practices on how to workaround the "endEditing" or how to forward the tap gesture to the `tableView` so that the **`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`** triggers out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you haven't a `tableView` that takes all the screen, otherwise you can close the keyboard in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Any way, you can do your stuff and the pass the event to the next responder (that is kind of class `UITableViewCell` if there is, so if user tap on the `tableView`):

```
- (void)tap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gr {
   [self.view endEditing:YES];

   UIResponder *responder = self;
    while (responder.nextResponder != nil){
        responder = responder.nextResponder;
        if ([responder isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    [responder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: I really like your idea, but not working right now... I tried debugging it, and it never reaches the "break;" and that means it doesn't find a UITableViewCell. So I printed each responder in the while cycle before the if statement with this result:

Comment: Pur the result yes. Maybe is a UITableView class the responder

Comment: (Yeah sorry, accidentally entered the comment before putting the result)

My storyboard hierarchy is the following: 
UINavigationController->UIViewController->UITableView (exactly, not 100% of screen)

<UIViewControllerWrapperView: ...>
<UINavigationTransitionView: ...>
<UILayoutContainerView: ...>
<NavigationTopViewController: ...>
<UIView: ...>
<InitialSlidingViewController: ...>
<UIWindow: ...>
<UIApplication: ...>
<SPTAppDelegate: ...>

Maybe the UITableView is inside the UIView... Not really sure :P

Comment: I wished comment would maintain form so the former one would me easier to read :(

Comment: So, probably you have to consider the `UIViewControllerWrapperView `. Did you try?